# How to change the path associated with numbapro module?

Tags: python, anaconda, numba-pro

I am trying to run a Python script that imports numbapro and I keep getting a bad path to the site-package location. When I import numbapro from the interactive command line I don't have any issues, but when I try to run this demo script from spyder, PyCharm, or prompt:

```
from numbapro import int32, float32
print(int32[:])           # 1D int32 array
print(float32[:,:])       # 2D float32 array
print(int32[:,:,:,:])     # 4D int32 array
```

I get this error:

```
/home/XXX/anaconda/bin/python 

/home/XXX/workspace/XXX/numba.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/XXX/workspace/XXX/numba.py", line 1, in <module>
    from numbapro import int32, float32
  File "/opt/anaconda1anaconda2anaconda3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numbapro/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    #
  File "/home/XXX/workspace/XXX/numba.py", line 1, in <module>
    from numbapro import int32, float32
ImportError: cannot import name int32

Process finished with exit code 1
```

For some reason the numbapro site-package keeps coming up as being in the /opt/... directory when it is actually under the default anaconda site-packages location. Any help would be greatly appreciated. My environment is Ubuntu 14.10, Python 2.7, and Anaconda 2.1.0.

Comment: Run `conda update numbapro` to make sure you have the latest version.

Comment: Thanks. I've already updated everything and reinstalled accelerate.